# Is modifying "Failover priority" parameter in RDS(AWS) requires downtime?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am wondering if modifying "Failover priority" in RDS can be cause of any downtime?
I can not find anything about it in the AWS documentation.